# How to handle json object in boolean using retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm struggling to display my json object to my textview `flagname` and set their color accordingly to their status. So basically this is a status from a service that has the handle time of 2 secs that auto refresh it to its current text view but my problem is that its displaying the package of the model class that i have from my json object. Can anyone help me or point out the cause of this problem I'm just a beginner so bear with me.

Comment: Post your JSON structure

Comment: @MichaelStoddart kindly check the edited post above

Comment: please remove code that is not related to your problem

Comment: @DmitriyPavlukhin yeah okay. I just edited it.